# XNA drawing and creating an array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, xna, draw

Hi all I am trying to create a game, and right now, I have a balloon class, which I want to currently create an amount of them via an array, and then draw then into the game.

Currently however it seems it is either only creating one instance of balloon or only drawing 1 instance. I'v looked over it multiple times, and from what I understand it should be looping through the entire array size (currently set at 10) and creating that many balloons, then updating and drawing that many.

Are you not able to do what I am currently doing with an array? Would I have to create each object sparately?

Here is the code of the two classes concerned.

GameLevel:
The class that creates the onjects and draws them.

```
        public partial class GameLevel : GameScreen
        {
            SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
            protected Game game;

            Texture2D balloonTexture;

            Balloon[] balloons = new Balloon[10];

            public GameLevel(Game game, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
                : base(game, spriteBatch)
            {
                this.game = game;
                this.spriteBatch = spriteBatch;
            }

            public void LoadContent()
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < balloons.Length; i++)
                {



                    int colour;
                    Random random = new Random();


                    colour = random.Next(1, 6);

                    switch (colour)
                    {
                        case 1: balloonTexture = Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/BlueBalloon");
                            break;
                        case 2: balloonTexture = Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/RedBalloon");
                            break;
                        case 3: balloonTexture = Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/YellowBalloon");
                            break;
                        case 4: balloonTexture = Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/GreenBalloon");
                            break;
                        case 5: balloonTexture = Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/PurpleBalloon");
                            break;
                    }
                    balloons[i] = new Balloon(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1152, 648), balloonTexture);
                    balloons[i].SetStartPosition();
                }
            }

            public void Update()
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < balloons.Length; i++)
                {
                    balloons[i].Update();
                }


            }



            public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < balloons.Length; i++)
                {

                    balloons[i].Draw(spriteBatch);
                }

                base.Draw(gameTime);
            }
        }
    }
```

Ballon Class:

```
    public class Balloon
    {

        Vector2 position;
        Vector2 motion;   
        Rectangle bounds;
        Rectangle screenBounds;
        public Texture2D texture;
        float balloonSpeed = 4;

        public Balloon(Rectangle screenBounds, Texture2D texture)     
        {       
            this.texture = texture;
            this.screenBounds = screenBounds;
        }

        public Rectangle Bounds
        {
            get
            {
                bounds.X = (int)position.X;
                bounds.Y = (int)position.Y;
                return bounds;
            }
        }


        public void Update()
        {
            position += motion * balloonSpeed;
        }

        private void CheckWallColision()
        {
            if (position.X < 0)
            {
                position.X = 0;
                motion.X *= -1;
            }

            if (position.X + texture.Width > screenBounds.Width)
            {
                position.X = screenBounds.Width - texture.Width;
                motion.X *= -1;
            }

            if (position.Y < 0)
            {
                position.Y = 0;
                motion.Y *= -1;
            }

            if (position.Y + texture.Height > screenBounds.Height)
            {

                position.Y = screenBounds.Height - texture.Height;
                motion.Y *= -1;
            }
        }

        public void SetStartPosition()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();

            motion = new Vector2(rand.Next(2, 6), -rand.Next(2, 6));
            motion.Normalize();

            position = new Vector2(rand.Next(100, 500), rand.Next(100, 500));

        }


        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at your code, my initial thought is they are all drawing on top of each other and the position is not getting calculated correctly. I would also suggest not creating a new instance of `Random` every time and instead keep one instance of it. It's possible to get the same seed and therefore the same values.

Comment: @TyCobb It's actually incredibly common to get the same seed - the seed is based entirely on the system clock, so a series of `Random` objects created at the same time will return the exact same series of values. Personally, I think it's a huge design flaw.

Comment: If you want something a little bit more _random_ each time your app runs use `Random random = new Random((int) DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x0000FFFF);` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the reason this is occurring is related to the way the `Random` object works. When one is constructed, it uses as its seed (from which it will generate *all* values) the system clock. This means that, if you generate numerous `Random` instances at the same time, every single one of them will return the same series of values. If you're using these values for positions, every single one of your objects will have the same position, and will be drawn over each other. In your case, because they're all the same size, it looks like only one was ever drawn.

To fix this, create a single instance of `Random` and just use `Next()` on that single instance whenever you need a new position.

Personally, I consider this a pretty significant design flaw - it doesn't seem amazingly intuitive that a series of `Random` objects created at the same time will be "random" in the *exact same way*. But: this is a good example of the fact that "random" values created by C#, and any other language, will in fact be *pseudo-random*, and when it comes to pseudo-randomness, implementation is very important.

Comment: I have done that, changed random to a global and called next in the forloops, however I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: @user1719605 Additionally, are you passing that single instance of `Random` to your balloon class? What's critical here is that a `Random` is not created within `SetStartPosition`.

Comment: I made it global within both classes, nothing changed. So I made it  public static in the GameLevel class and called that version in Balloon Class and seemed to do the trick.